# How to improve the model from the loss and accuracy functions

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I am training a binary classification model (CNN) using keras. I have added the loss and accuracy function got form the training model. Should one conclude that its model has an accuracy of about 82% based on the following functions, or is it better to continue improving the hyperparameters ?
Is the model really learning something ? [image]

Comment: Well, quickly looking to it, your model is learning indeed, but your model now suffers from overfitting, it started memorizing the training set. That may be one of the reason that your test loss is increasing while train loss is decreasing. Research about "how to overcome overfitting".

Comment: Thanks for your answer @null . The overfitting starts after the 3rd epoch, which corresponds to about 82%. Is it guarantee that overcoming the overfitting will increase the accuracy ?

Comment: I believe the `machine-learning` tag is mainly for implemented related questions. You will find better answers at stats.stackexchange.com or ai.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Kyv well "guaranteed" is a strong word but I believe it'll get better with regularization, have you considered using dropout? Btw if you use dropout it may take more epochs for model to converge.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your model seems to be learning something. To know for sure, I would need to understand what the baseline accuracy is (model predicting randomly). If your model doesn't learn anything, it should have a similar accuracy to that of a completely random model.

As pointed out, your model seems to be overfitting, since the accuracy is increasing on the training set, while it is decreasing on the test set. We can see a
similar effect on the loss function.

Since your loss is still decreasing, I would consider training the model longer. If you do this, it would be helpful to add some regularization (dropout for example). For images, you can also add some noise to some of your input images.